# Hide php code if?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

What I want to do is really simple but I'm obviously not great and very new to PHP. I'm using woocommerce for my store and a woocommerce add on called "woocommerce scheduler" to set a start and end time specific products are for sale each day.

The way the scheduling program works is you set start and end times with 24hr clock example 10am (10:00) to 8pm (20:00) the product can be purchased anytime from 8am-10pm after 10pm the plugin "hides" the add to cart button ans displays a custom message such as "Currently Unavailable" and you can't purchase the item.

I ran into 2 problems one of which is solved

1. I wanted the plugin to show the start time the product would become available with the unavailable message basically it would say "unavailable until 8am"

So the solution to that problem was a plugin called **Advanced Custom Fields**
and creating a custom field that I can set on the product page and then I can display by putting this php code if the feild is empty on another product page it isn't displayed `<?php if( get_field('product_time') ): ?>
    <p>Available at <?php the_field('product_time'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>`
 into my single product page template file.

I got that working just fine. Now my second issue that I can't solve.

2. I want to **hide** the code that shows the time when the unavailable message is hidden because the product is in the hours where it is available for purchase. So how would I go about this?

I found the bit of code that pulls the unavailable message but it is a js. file so I cant put the php I have into that file.

wdm_validate.js

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                               jQuery('.cart').html('<p class = "wdm_message3">'+wdm_message.wdm_expiration_message+'  </p>');
 });
```

this is the bit in the php file for the scheduler plugin that calls that js file

woocommerce_scheduler.php

```
if($wdm_start_date <= $d && $d<=$wdm_end_date && $str_start_time <=
    $curtime && $curtime <= $str_end_time) {
}else{
    //echo "<style>.cart{display:none;}</style>";
    //echo "hello";
    //exit;
    wp_enqueue_script('wdm_expiration_message',plugins_url('js/wdm_validate.js',__FILE__),
        array('jquery'));
    $data = array(
        'wdm_expiration_message' => get_option( 'woocommerce_custom_product_expiration',true )
        );
    wp_localize_script('wdm_expiration_message','wdm_message',$data);
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to display something after a certain time? Meaning (if time >= the_time_i_want_item_to_apear, then show_item() ? Something like that?

Comment: I hope there is some back-end validation too or people can get around your restrictions just by disabling JavaScript. Not to mention people using screen readers would never be notified of the availability.

Comment: Why not just add a little more conditional logic to the `if(get_field())` check?

Answer (score 0):

In your custom code just add class to `<p>` tag and perform following:-

```
<?php if( get_field('product_time') ): ?>
    <p class='wdm_available'>Available at <?php the_field('product_time'); ?></p>
<script>
       jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     //checking wdm_message3 i.e. expiration message exist or not
              if(!jQuery('.wdm_message3').is(':visible')){
                jQuery('.wdm_available').hide();
                 }
            });
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: when using your code the time message was hidden when the product was available for purchase but it was also hidden when the product wasn't available for purchase which is when the message should have been showing. A friend looked at your code for me and it guided him into a working solution so thank you so much for your help. I have included the code in an answer to my question separately but thank you for the quick reply

Answer (score 0):

adding this code to my price.php template page in woocommerce got me exactly what I needed. The time is hidden when the product is available and shows when the item is not available for sale letting my customer know what time they can purchase it.

```
<?php if( get_field('product_time') ): ?>
        <p class='wdm_available'>Unavailable Until <?php the_field('product_time'); ?></p>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){

            // set a timeout function to get around brief delay in scheduler script
            setTimeout(function(){

                //check if scheduler message is NOT visible
                if(!jQuery('.wdm_message3').is(':visible')) {
                    // if not, hide custom availabilty time message
                    jQuery('.wdm_available').hide();
                }
            }, 0);
        });
    </script>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way for me to know the format of your custom field, but you should be able to run a comparison against the current time. As an idea:

```
$current_time = time();

$sale_time = get_field('product_time');

if( $sale_time && $sale_time < $current_time ): ?>
        <p class='wdm_available'>Unavailable Until <?php the_field('product_time'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```